# Play Framework - how to bind form to a session field

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Is there a way I can get some parameters from headers, say cookie (in my case logged in userId), and then apply it to a form so I know who is submitting the ticket?

SupportForm
 
`supportForm:Form[SupportTicket] = Form(mapping( 
  "question" -> text,
   "Priority" -> text 
)(SupportTicket.Apply)(SupportTicket.Unapply)`

What are the good practises here? 
Is request present as an implicit when the call to Apply is made so that I can use it (and is this even a good practise?)

EDIT: One of the issues, ofcourse is someone spoofing if I were to create a hidden field with this value. I could encrypt, but the issue again is to somehow verify and return the form, not sure how this can be done....

Comment: Also, can I throw in Apply? Would that take the form back to user?

Comment: To answer the question in my previous comment, no, throwing in apply would not take the form back to user. (at least throwing a <code>new exception</code> wouldn't)

Comment: If a Form is applied from an Action, then the request should be implicitly in scope.

Comment: @Ashalynd How should I return the form to the user.. ? Throw wouldn't work.

Comment: @Ashalynd I checked and the request is implicitly not in scope. The request is searched where Object.Apply is called, This is inside Form( mapping( <fields> ) (Object.Apply) (Object.unapply ) ). So, no, request isn't available.